# How to convert SGML to XML by Opensp?

Tags: xml, sgml

I want to convert SGML to XML and i have searched so many things many people are advising to use OpenSp tool  https://sourceforge.net/projects/openjade/files/opensp/1.5.2/. included OpenSP-1.5.2-win32.zip which has osx.exe 
and  http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/index.htm. for its documentation,
 so using this link I got source file and instruction but my problem is i am not able to understand how to use this tool and build-win32.bat and how to execute the given command in this link, if anyone knows about it please help me.

Comment: You don't need build-win32.bat. You already have the osx.exe executable. To convert from SGML to XML, execute it, like this: `osx.exe input.sgml > output.xml`.

Comment: thanks for your comment but nothing is happening, what i did just downloaded that file where osx.exe was available, opened osx.exe command  prompt and as you suggested executed like same way "osx.exe input.sgml > output.xml"  and enter after that nothing happened no error, no message.

Comment: Is there a file called output.xml (or whatever you chose to call it)? Is there anything in it?

Comment: There is nothing only osx.exe.

Comment: Don't you have an SGML file as input?

Comment: Yes i have the file named 556101601_ATA.SGM. Is there any way that i can show you this file?

Comment: And is that file in the same directory as osx.exe? If you run `osx.exe 556101601_ATA.SGM` does anything happen?

Comment: yes both .SGML file and osx.exe are in same folder but nothing is happening.

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: All I know is that I have been able to use osx.exe before. I don't have it now. And I cannot explain your problem. I am very sorry.

Comment: instead of using osx command prompt i executed your given command osx.exe input.sgml > output.xml in windows command prompt now its working.Thanks